# Behavior of intellisense in solution of multiple projects?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

There is no way (at least for me) to find out information for this very specific question.

I need to know, If Solution in Visual Studio has multiple projects, how does intellisense works in that case:

> 1. does it scan all projects, and spends valuable computer resources for all projects, OR
> 2. does intellisense work only for the project I'm currently working on in solution?

If the answer is **case 1.** (and hopefully you have some reference to backup this claim) then I wan't to know if there is anything I can to to limit inellisense activity to work only on a project I currently have opened.

I don't know but I think this approach could help speed up intellisense, and maybe also help reduce the amount of background tasks related to regualar intellisense scans.

thsese projects are not really small, and I have over 20 of them in one solution, (not much I can do about that btw.), and I'm getting tired of seeing slow performance due to these frequent parsings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.does it scan all projects, and spends valuable computer resources for all projects, OR
>
> 2.does intellisense work only for the project I'm currently working on in solution?

**The answer, of course, is case 1.** Intellisense works by default on the entire solution, not on a single project. **It just subdivides individual files**, such as c++, c#, js, XML, and so on. You can got it from `Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->(c#/c++/javascript/....)-->general/IntelliSense`. You can then enable or disable Intellisense based on a single file type.

> does intellisense work only for the project I'm currently working on
> in solution?

**I think the answer is negative.** I looked for a lot of documents on Intellisense and didn't find any examples of Intellisense being used for a project. This feature of Intellisense is not proposed by Microsoft. If you want this feature,  you could [suggest a feature to the Support Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to get their attention.

**In addition**, maybe it's not Intellisense that affects VS performance. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019) to improve VS performance.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you Qian, I've researched a lot regarding intellisense, read many MS articles, instellisense improved a lot in recent 2 yrs. you information additionally improves my understanding.

Comment: Glad to know my answer helps you understand the mechanism of Intellisense. If you have any other related issues, please feel free to let us know:)